# How can I save http requests from applications in c#?

Tags: c#

When I connect my phone to iTunes it sends a request to a certain server so I have managed to  divert to my server which I think I don't have the file or files that iTunes asks for but I would like to know what iTunes is requesting.

Here  is my code

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace SimpleWebServer
{
class Server
{
    /************************************\
     * Acrobyte Http Web Server           *
     * Alexio Puk2sefu                   *
     * www.acrobytemob.com                *
     * Alexiopuk2sefu@acrobytemob.com            *
    \************************************/

    public bool running = false; // Is it running?

    private int timeout = 8; // Time limit for data transfers.
    private Encoding charEncoder = Encoding.UTF8; // To encode string
    private Socket serverSocket; // Our server socket
    private string contentPath; // Root path of our contents

    // Content types that are supported by our server
    // You can add more...
    // To see other types: http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml
    private Dictionary<string, string> extensions = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    { 
        //{ "extension", "content type" }
        { "htm", "text/html" },
        { "html", "text/html" },
        { "xml", "text/xml" },
        { "txt", "text/plain" },
        { "css", "text/css" },
        { "png", "image/png" },
        { "gif", "image/gif" },
        { "jpg", "image/jpg" },
        { "jpeg", "image/jpeg" },
        { "zip", "application/zip"},
        { "plist", "application/plist"},
        { "app", "application/app"},
        { "file", "application/file"}
    };

    public bool start(IPAddress ipAddress, int port, int maxNOfCon, string contentPath)
    {
        if (running) return false; // If it is already running, exit.

        try
        {
            // A tcp/ip socket (ipv4)
            serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port));
            serverSocket.Listen(maxNOfCon);
            serverSocket.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            serverSocket.SendTimeout = timeout;
            running = true;
            this.contentPath = contentPath;
        }
        catch { return false; }

        // Our thread that will listen connection requests and create new threads to handle them.
        Thread requestListenerT = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (running)
            {
                Socket clientSocket;
                try
                {
                    clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
                    // Create new thread to handle the request and continue to listen the socket.
                    Thread requestHandler = new Thread(() =>
                    {
                        clientSocket.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
                        clientSocket.SendTimeout = timeout;
                        try { handleTheRequest(clientSocket); }
                        catch
                        {
                            try { clientSocket.Close(); } catch { }
                        }
                    });
                    requestHandler.Start();
                }
                catch{}
            }
        });
        requestListenerT.Start();

        return true;
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        if (running)
        {
            running = false;
            try { serverSocket.Close(); }
            catch { }
            serverSocket = null;
        }
    }

    private void handleTheRequest(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[10240]; // 10 kb, just in case
        int receivedBCount = clientSocket.Receive(buffer); // Receive the request
        string strReceived = charEncoder.GetString(buffer, 0, receivedBCount);

        // Parse the method of the request
        string httpMethod = strReceived.Substring(0, strReceived.IndexOf(" "));

        int start = strReceived.IndexOf(httpMethod) + httpMethod.Length + 1;
        int length = strReceived.LastIndexOf("HTTP") - start - 1;
        string requestedUrl = strReceived.Substring(start, length);

        string requestedFile;
        if (httpMethod.Equals("GET") || httpMethod.Equals("POST"))
            requestedFile = requestedUrl.Split('?')[0];
        else // You can implement other methods...
        {
            notImplemented(clientSocket);
            return;
        }

        requestedFile = requestedFile.Replace("/", "\\").Replace("\\..", ""); // Not to go back
        start = requestedFile.LastIndexOf('.') + 1;
        if (start > 0)
        {
            length = requestedFile.Length - start;
            string extension = requestedFile.Substring(start, length);
            if (extensions.ContainsKey(extension)) // Do we support this extension?
                if (File.Exists(contentPath + requestedFile)) // If yes check existence
                    // Everything is OK, send requested file with correct content type:
                    sendOkResponse(clientSocket, File.ReadAllBytes(contentPath + requestedFile), extensions[extension]);
                else
                    notFound(clientSocket); // We don't support this extension. We are assuming that it doesn't exist.
        }
        else
        {
            // If file is not specified try to send index.htm or index.html
            // You can add more (for example "default.html")
            if (requestedFile.Substring(length - 1, 1) != "\\")
                requestedFile += "\\";
            if (File.Exists(contentPath + requestedFile + "index.htm"))
                sendOkResponse(clientSocket, File.ReadAllBytes(contentPath + requestedFile + "\\index.htm"), "text/html");
            else if (File.Exists(contentPath + requestedFile + "index.html"))
                sendOkResponse(clientSocket, File.ReadAllBytes(contentPath + requestedFile + "\\index.html"), "text/html");
            else
                notFound(clientSocket);
        }
    }

    private void notImplemented(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        sendResponse(clientSocket, "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body><h2>Atasoy Simple Web Server</h2><div>501 - Method Not Implemented</div></body></html>", "501 Not Implemented", "text/html");
    }

    private void notFound(Socket clientSocket)
    {
        sendResponse(clientSocket, "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body><h2>Atasoy Simple Web Server</h2><div>404 - Not Found</div></body></html>", "404 Not Found", "text/html");
    }

    private void sendOkResponse(Socket clientSocket, byte[] bContent, string contentType)
    {
        sendResponse(clientSocket, bContent, "200 OK", contentType);
    }

    // For strings
    private void sendResponse(Socket clientSocket, string strContent, string responseCode, string contentType)
    {
        byte[] bContent = charEncoder.GetBytes(strContent);
        sendResponse(clientSocket, bContent, responseCode, contentType);
    }

    // For byte arrays
    private void sendResponse(Socket clientSocket, byte[] bContent, string responseCode, string contentType)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bHeader = charEncoder.GetBytes(
                                "HTTP/1.1 " + responseCode + "\r\n"
                              + "Server: Acrobyte Web Server\r\n"
                              + "Content-Length: " + bContent.Length.ToString() + "\r\n"
                              + "Connection: close\r\n"
                              + "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n\r\n");
            clientSocket.Send(bHeader);
            clientSocket.Send(bContent);
            clientSocket.Close();
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
}
```

So the request is coming to this server but iTunes says error and I simply would like to save that request and view it later

Comment: why not use IIS and look at its log files

Comment: better idea let me try that